# Customze shortcuts of Chrome profile on the desktop (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, shortcuts, customization

I'm using different profiles for the Chrome browser and created shortcuts on the desktop (in Ubuntu 20.04). However, I'm trying to customize the icon and description of each shortcut.

At the moment I have:

[image: Chrome shortcuts]

The shortcut icons are identical and I can't rename them either.

I want them to look like this:

[image: Customized]

-with a customized picture and renamed

The code:

```
~/Desktop$ls -l
-rwxrw-r-- 1 user user  249 Jan  1 15:18 Michelle.desktop
-rwxrw-r-- 1 user user  223 Dec 30 17:04 Richard.desktop
```

```
~/Desktop$cat Richard.desktop
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=.../orange.png
Exec=google-chrome --profile-directory=Default
Name[en_US]=Chrome-Default
Name=Chrome-Default
Icon=google-chrome
```

```
~/Desktop$cat Michelle.desktop
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=.../Netscape-icon.png
Exec=google-chrome --profile-directory=Profile\ 1
Name[en_US]=Chrome-Profile\ 1
Name=Chrome-Profile\ 1
Icon=google-chrome
```

Thank you

Comment: Providing the output of `ls -l Desktop/` and `cat /Desktop/<.desktop-name>` will be useful

Answer (score 1):

For each Chromium instance to be recognized as a different application, you will need to start these up with a custom WM_CLASS. You can do so by providing the option `--class myprofile1` to your `Exec=` line (change `myprofile1` to the name of your choice). Then add a line `StartupWMClass=myprofile1` to have the desktop environment connect that instance with that specific `.desktop` file.